# Max of subtable with double condition

Tags: excel, max

Let's say I have the following table:

A   | B
3.1 | 13
3.2 | 5
3.3 | 11
3.4 | 3
3.5 | 14

I would like to get the maximum of column B when value of A range between 2 numbers. I tried:

`{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5>3.1,$B$2:$B$5))}` = 14

`{=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5<3.5,$B$2:$B$5))}` = 13

but

`{=MAX(IF(AND($A$2:$A$5>3.1,$A$2:$A$5<3.5),$B$2:$B$5))}` **= 0**

Comment: do any of these previous questions help ?  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+maxif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will resolve (with array):

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5>3.1,IF($A$2:$A$5<3.5,$B$2:$B$5,""),""))
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't use entire column references within an array formula. If you only have data as far as, for example, row 100, then that formula is being forced to calculate more than 2 million cells more than necessary. Just 50 or so instances of such a formula will practically force Excel to crash.